# Randomly selecting columns then displaying the rest of the non randomly selected data

Tags: r, dataframe

The Code is provided below:

df is my data set 128 x 5000

```
test_random  <- df[, sample(ncol(df), 32)] 
training_random <-  df[-test_random, ]
```

Error message :

> Error in df[test_random, ] :
>   only 0's may be mixed with negative subscripts

Any thoughts on how to display the training_random subset?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have almost done it:

```
test_random  <- df[, -sample(ncol(df), 32)] 


ncol(test_random)
```

Comment: If the OP wants both the 32 columns df and the other df, call `sample` just one time: `inx <- sample(etc)`. Then `df[, inx]` and `df[, -inx]` are the two df's the OP wants.

Comment: @Salman yes thank you that worked. thank you so much

Comment: @AllenRahrooh could you please acept the answer?

Comment: @Salman ok accepted, sorry new to this website